# How does telegraf input plugin like [[inputs.mem]] fetch data?

Tags: telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin

When we need memory related stats we add input plugin in `telegraf.conf` file.

```
[[inputs.mem]]
```

- For application stats we keep input as statsd, we push stats from application using UDP to telegraf using its host and port.

```
[[inputs.statsd]]
```

Could someone explain how does `[[inputs.mem]]` input plugins get data related to memory? Because no one is pushing data to telegraf in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Telegraf retrieves system data using system libraries written for Go.  At this time it is using the [gopsutil](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil) library.  This library's link above includes an example of how it could be used within any Go program.

```
func main() {
    v, _ := mem.VirtualMemory()

    // almost every return value is a struct
    fmt.Printf("Total: %v, Free:%v, UsedPercent:%f%%\n", v.Total, v.Free, v.UsedPercent)

    // convert to JSON. String() is also implemented
    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

This library supports a number of different operating systems and has modules for a variety of system information such as cpu, memory, disk, and networking usage.  You can see where these are incorporated into the telegraf project [here](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/inputs/system/system.go).